# Remote Debug of Celery using rdb

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to do some debuging on celery task using rdb but despite the fact that I can connect to the socket using telnet it doesn't give me any data, looks like Pdb is broken and doesn't have any data to inspect

It starts with this lane

> c:\python27\lib\contextlib.py(21)**exit**()-> def **exit**(self, type, value, traceback):(Pdb)

My setup is RabbitMQ and Celery running on localhost together with python virtual env

Any idea what may be wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem and finds their way here from google, I can't explain *why* rdb drops you into the middle of contextlib but I have found that if you execute the `r(eturn)` command a couple times you'll work your way back into the function you made your `rdb.set_trace()` call from.